# installing ssl on a virtualserver a vps

Tags: ssl, virtualhost, ssl-certificate

My Problem:

Installing SSL on VPS, for one domain.

My server:

> Ubunutu / Apache / mod_ssl / openssl
>
> Using Virutalmin / Webmin
>
> Two IP address.

I have four domains hosted on my vps, i.e. there are 4 virutal servers. On one of the domain i.e. one of the virtual server I wish to install comodo SSL.

Steps I have taken so far:

> 1. Using virutalmin, generated CSR and activated the SSL from comodo.
> 2. Using virtualmin, uploaded the SSL certificate.

( I got three other CA files, but I have no idea where to put them. )

Now I'm getting secure connection failed error. How should I go about enabling SSL for only one domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you've selected the domain from the drop-down, and have SSL enabled (Edit Virtual Server > Enabled features > SSL website enabled?).

Then go to Server Configuration > Manage SSL Certificate. There's a tab where you can paste the CA cert(s). If you were given several, make sure they are all for your particular setup, and if so, try pasting them one after the other.